# Summing a column in excel that is of custom type h:mm

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am summing a column of custom type h:mm.

Problem is, if the total hours goes over 24, my SUM resets to 0 and as a result the final number is not correct.

I want the result to be like: 75 hours.
But since the result resets, I have no idea how many times it counted past 24 hours.

my equestion:

SUM(A2:A90)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [h]:mm:ss format should be another value in the custom list under (in Excel 2003)

```
Format -> cells -> Number tab
```

then

```
category = custom
```

then scroll down the "Type" list until you find

```
[h]:mm:ss
```

If it's not there you can type it into the single box under where it says "Type:" on the right hand side of the tab.